# Python tkinter xlsxwriter trying to export user input to excel file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import sys,math,random,datetime,os,time
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from time import gmtime, strftime
import xlsxwriter

export = "Excel"
current_time = strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", gmtime())

root = Tk()
e1 = Entry()
e1.insert(10, "First Name")
e2 = Entry()
e2.insert(10, "Last Name")
```

Here is where I am trying to format variable to become string.

```
fullname = "%s %s" % (e1, e2)
title = ["Titan Tech", "Caleb Fahlgren made this!", "Python is life!", "FIRST Robotics!","Doesn't this make your life easier?"]
title = (random.choice(title))
root.title(title)
root.geometry("640x600")

#Submit Button
def Submit():
    submit = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Submit Entry", "Are you sure you want to submit?")
    if submit == "yes":
```

Xlsx program.

```
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('TitanTechSummary.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
        worksheet.write('A1', 'Name:',bold)
```

This is where I am trying to write the players input for name. Or the tkinter Entry(). But I keep getting like a weird decimal number when I look at the excel document. I keep getting this in the B1 field '.140041879004720 .140041884602944'

```
        worksheet.write_string('B1',fullname, bold)
        worksheet.write('C1', 'Date:',bold)
```

I also want to do the same thing with the date.

```
        worksheet.write('D1', 'Date')


        workbook.close()
        userconfirm = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Save","Your entry has been saved to an " + export + " document!")


def keypress(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()


def Quit():
    quitask = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?")
    if quitask == "yes":
            root.destroy()
def Insert():
    filen = askopenfilename()
    filen1 = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Saved", "If you opened a picture we saved it!")

firstname = Label(root, text="First Name",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
lastname = Label(root, text="Last Name",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
time = Label(root, text=current_time, font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="black")

TextArea = Text()
ScrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
ScrollBar.config(command=TextArea.yview)
TextArea.config(yscrollcommand=ScrollBar.set)
ScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

Submit = Button(root, fg="white", bg="green", text="Submit", width=50, command=Submit, activebackground="yellow")
Quit = Button(root, fg="white", bg="green", text="Quit", width=50, command=Quit,activebackground="yellow")
Insert = Button(root,fg="white", bg="green", text="Insert Images", width=50, command=Insert,activebackground="yellow")

root.bind_all('<Key>', keypress)
firstname.pack()
e1.pack()
lastname.pack()
e2.pack()
time.pack()
TextArea.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
Insert.pack()
Submit.pack()
Quit.pack() 

mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `fullname = "%s %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get())` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
fullname = "%s %s" % (e1, e2)
```

`e1` and `e2` are entry widgets. Their string representation (ie: if you do `str(e1)`) is going to be "a weird decimal number".

You need to be calling the `get()` method of the widget to get the contents:

```
fullname = "%s %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get())
```

Comment: @CalebFahlgren: there is no such thing as a String widget. I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: How would I write to an existing Excel file not overwrite it.